# pandas: how to merge 2 dataframes on 'X' from df1 and f['Y'] from df2

Tags: python, pandas

i want to merge 2 dataframes df1 and df2, 
 using left_on:  col 'X' from df1, 
 using right_on: result of function f apply to col 'Y' from df2.

I may make a specific columns 'Z' result of f(df2['Y']) , but i want to avoid it.

is it possible ?

Comment: Why not just add the column, do the merge and then drop the column?

Comment: Edchum, you re right this is the most simple approach, but i am always scared adding temporary new columns on huge dataframe (when number of row > 50000).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `left_on` and `right_on` arguments to [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
In [11]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [2, 4]], columns=["X", "A"])

In [12]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5], [2, 6]], columns=["Z", "B"])

In [13]: df1.merge(df2, left_on=["X"], right_on=["Z"])
Out[13]:
   X  A  Z  B
0  1  3  1  5
1  2  4  2  6
```